# Can I use the word "sceptical" this way?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

> I am **sceptical** about my vacation plan.

Is this the correct way to write? I wanted to express doubt about my vacation schedule. I have to tell someone that my vacation schedule has yet to be finalized and I am not sure when I will be able to go.

Comment: You just say, **My vacation schedule has yet to be finalized and I am not sure when I will be able to go.**. Or "I have not fixed my vacation plan (schedule) yet". Why do you have to use the word "sceptical"? Did you try to find what it means?

Comment: I wanted to express doubt about my vacation schedule ,

Comment: Then, you can say **I am not sure**.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say "I am skeptical *of* my vacation plan."

Answer (score 1):

To be sceptical about something is to mistrust it.

> My brother says he saw the Loch Ness monster, but I am sceptical.

I am not convinced my brother is lying, but nor am I convinced he is telling the truth. I don't know, so I am sceptical.

> The government think this is the right policy, but I am sceptical.

Maybe it is, but you suspect it probably isn't.

If you have produced a vacation schedule and your boss has said it will probably be fine, but you suspect when it gets closer he might decide you are too busy, then you could say

> I have a vacation schedule but I am sceptical as to whether my boss will honour it

However if you have simply not decided on your vacation plans yet then sceptical is not the right word to use.